# Where is the my bLabel ？

Tags: ios

[image]

bLabel don't show。But if the aLabel.clipsToBounds = YES. bLabel will show.
Add button will display。I want to know why, thank you

Comment: Request: post code as actual code, not images. This will help others to quickly reproduce the situation, also, images on image-hosting tends to become outdated and deleted, which will make this question confusing in future.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code screen shot. You are adding bLable to aLable. Check the line number 35 in your screen shot. `[aLabel addSubview: bLabel]`.As per your code the bLabel is adding to aLable. aLable is hiding bLabel because of same color code.  That's you are not seeing the bLable in screen.